# Null after logrotate copytruncate

Tags: linux, log-files, logrotate

I am using `logrotate` to manage my logs. As I have to manage a bunch of log files. My logrotate config looks like

```
/log/typeA*.log
/log/typeB*.log
/log/typeC*.log{
        daily
        rotate 7
        copytruncate
        size 1M
        compress
        su root root
        create 0644 root root
        missingok
}
```

After logrotation is complete I see bunch of null characters in the beginning of file. Which looks like

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

Looks like infinitely long string. Also file size looks similar.
There is solution suggested https://serverfault.com/a/510470 to use postrotate script like

```
postrotate
   sed -i -e 's/\o00//g' session.timing.1
endscript
```

But as I am applying this to bunchg of files I don't have any specific name like `session.timing.1`  is there any way to get it done generically? I want this operation to be done for all file of `typeA_date1.log` `typeA_date2.log` and so on....
Or do you suggest any other method that can be useful here?

Answer (score 0):

i get the same problem. After read the [`logrotate`](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate) code, i think when the program keep writing log message with a opened file, can only use `copytruncate` mode, but this mode also makes file hole by [`ftruncate`](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate/blob/88b2de7bc6d57134e118c21655ae05d6461dc8ae/logrotate.c#L1234) and fill with `NULL` characters.

Some tips:

1. change the program method for log, which not need use `copytruncate` mode
2. managed by systemd with `syslog` configure, see [how to](https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file.html)
3. managed by systemd (version 236 or newer) which can set `StandardOutput` to a file, so maybe can use `logrotate` with `create` mode (not sure)